# TTS - Character By Character

Tags: android, android-sqlite, text-to-speech

Building a TTS Application

App is displaying word on swipe from SQLite
and speak immediately

but if user swiping twice or thrice quickly to skip word, it still speaks the old (i.e first word)

**SPEAK**

```
public void speak(){
    text = txt_word.getText().toString();
    final char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(chars.length), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    textToSpeech.setPitch((float) 0.80);

    final boolean[] stop = {false};

    final int delay = 700;
    final int[] i = {0};
    final Handler handler=  new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                textToSpeech.speak(String.valueOf(chars[i[0]]),TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
            } else {
                textToSpeech.speak(String.valueOf(chars[i[0]]), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }

            i[0]++;
            if(i[0]>=chars.length){
                stop[0] =true;

            }
            //do your work here..

            if (!stop[0]) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }
    }, delay);
    textToSpeech.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
    //Toast.makeText(this,text , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**SWIPE CALL**

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    if (e1.getX() > e2.getX()) {
        Cursor c = db.random();
        c.moveToFirst();
        txt_word.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("word")));
        speak();
    }
```

Comment: Call stop() before calling new speak()
 if (tts.isSpeaking()) {
            if (tts.stop() == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
               //your code
            }
        }
I am not sure it will work or not but this is recommended

Comment: didn't worked

if(textToSpeech.isSpeaking()){
                if(textToSpeech.stop()==textToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                    speak();
                }
            }else{
                speak();
            }

@Harshkurra

Comment: Please also cancel or remove your last runnable or delay  txt_word.setText() & speak()

Answer (score 0):

After little bit of Google

```
onCreate------
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Create Method

```
private Runnable speakCharackters = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        chars = txt_word.getText().toString().toCharArray();

        textToSpeech.speak(String.valueOf(chars[i]),TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
        txt_character.setText(String.valueOf(chars[i]));
        i++;

        if(i>=chars.length){
            i=0;
            handler.removeCallbacks(speakCharackters);

        }else{
            handler.postDelayed(speakCharackters,delay);
        }

    }
};
```

and before again starting new word

```
handler.removeCallbacks(speakCharackters);
handler.postDelayed(speakCharackters, delay);
```

Comment: sorry for late in posting answer